# Binary Tree algorithms to calculate min and max

Tags: algorithm

I have to calculate min and max value in a binary tree, **NOT SEARCH BINARY TREE**, I think this function can be a solution for this problem.

```
void min_max(node* t, int& m, int &M)
{
   if(!t)
     return;

   if(t->value>M)
     M = t->value;

   if(t->value<m)
     m = t->value;

   min_max(t->left,m,M);
   min_max(t->right,m,M);
}
```

Can someone tell me if it really search a minimum and maximum value?

Comment: The logic looks okay. Have you tested it?

Comment: It looks right. Also, when calling it for the root you could initialize `m` and `M` to the value in the root, *i.e.* call it like this: `min_max(root, root->value, root->value);`

Comment: Thanks , I had had a doubt because I saw a solution , but much more complicated.